# My background image doesn't work

Tags: html, css

```css
#gtco-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: #4d4d4d;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  #gtco-header.gtco-cover {
    height: inherit !important;
    padding: 3em 0 !important;
  }
}
#gtco-header .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-image: url(iamges/68410027-dota-2-logo-wallpapers.jpg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<header id="gtco-header" class="gtco-cover gtco-cover-md" style="background-image: url(http://www.guoguiyan.com/data/out/59/68410027-dota-2-logo-wallpapers.jpg)" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="gtco-container">
    <div class="row row-mt-15em">
      <div class="col-md-12 mt-text text-center animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInUp">
        <h1>We Build <strong>Branded Platforms</strong></h1>
        <h2>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia.</h2>
        <div class="text-center">
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kr7KDCsIws" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg popup-video">Watch the video</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I'm trying to make a image fit in the header box I got but, for some reason it wont change no matter what I do.

As seen in the two pictures (and code blocks) of my html and css, that I have a background color. I have a background image in the CSS, I have tried one in HTML (in the pictures both codes are in use but I have tried both without one and another).

I have an image folder in the main folder where the HTML file is which contains the pictures I use and some of them works but not the new pictures I have downloaded.

I have tried using them through my download links, linking through folders, using the URL and linking from the web, but no luck.

Anyone got an idea? This is due to this Friday.

Comment: please add you code not images

Comment: Like ^ said, please share all your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a height, because you've already determined the "size" of your element with `position: absolute` and `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` - which is basically the same as `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` relative to the parent element.

Make sure to remove the background of your `.gtco-header`, which would cover the image.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

#gtco-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /* background: #4d4d4d; */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  #gtco-header.gtco-cover {
    height: inherit !important;
    padding: 3em 0 !important;
  }
}

#gtco-header .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); */
  background: url(//unsplash.it/500/500/) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<header id="gtco-header" class="gtco-cover gtco-cover-md" style="background-image: url(http://www.guoguiyan.com/data/out/59/68410027-dota-2-logo-wallpapers.jpg)" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="gtco-container">
    <div class="row row-mt-15em">
      <div class="col-md-12 mt-text text-center animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInUp">
        <h1>We Build <strong>Branded Platforms</strong></h1>
        <h2>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia.</h2>
        <div class="text-center">
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kr7KDCsIws" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg popup-video">Watch the video</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: @Mikeskovby Did my answer help you? If so, can you please mark it as the accepted answer. If you still have any questions, feel free to ask me more :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
background-size:100% 100%;
height:300px; 
background-image: url("your image url");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```